# Is it possible to obtain the SQL statements generated by Class::DBI?

Tags: perl, orm, class-dbi

I want to find the exact SQL statements that are generated by a Perl ORM package such as [Class::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class::DBI). I am *not* looking for SQL generated for simple inserts and deletes, but for row modifications that result from slightly complicated object manipulations (inserting rows in a table which is a child of a row in a parent table, for example)

Is there some way to get it?

Comment: Why and how would you like to get the SQL? If it's a one time thing, that's not so hard. If you want to do it continually inside the program and do fancy stuff with it, that's a bit harder.

Comment: Here is what I had in mind: I have to keep two databases in sync. Only one of these is an active database. The other just holds a copy of the active one. Since the connection between the two is not always guaranteed to be stable, I want to log all SQL statements generated on one database, collect them in a file, transfer the file over the network and run all statements in a single transaction on the passive database. Unfortunately, for reasons beyond my control, I have no access to replication tools or 2-phase commits which would ideally be the right way to address this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class::DBI uses DBI under the hood, so you can enable tracing of all SQL statements via an environment variable:

```
DBI_TRACE=3=dbi.log your-perl-script
```

Or inside of Perl, before executing any statements:

```
use DBI;
DBI->trace(2, 'dbi.log');
```

See http://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING

Answer (score 2):

Since you said "such as"…

You can set the environment variable `DBIC_TRACE` to `1` if you are using [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class) (which has [a Class::DBI compatibility layer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Class::CDBICompat)).

Comment: I think that DBI::Profile would be similarly useful, although I haven' t tried it and my general loathing of ORMs dissuades me from trying :)